# is there any solution for this JQuery editablecontent code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a graduation website project and I want to make the text editable. I tried this jQuery code but it did not work for me.

I am using Bootstrap CSS and jQuery. When I add other JS or jQuery code it never works for me.

the cdns add is what i am using in building the website

```
// that's what i use like cdns in my website//
<!--bootsrap script-->

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--end bootsrap script-->

<!--MDBOOTSTRAP script LINKS-->

<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.5/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
 <!--MDBOOTSTRAP scriptLINKS end-->

////
```

```js
$('.edit').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.box').addClass('editable');
  $('.text').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
  $('.save').show();
});

$('.save').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.box').removeClass('editable');
  $('.text').removeAttr('contenteditable');
  $('.edit').show();
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: -6%;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
}

.editable {
  border-color: #bd0f18;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #555;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.edit,
.save {
  width: 60px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.edit {
  background: #557a11;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}

.save {
  display: none;
  background: #bd0f18;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.box:hover .edit {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-7 pl box">
  <span class="edit">edit</span>
  <span class="save">save</span>
  <div class="text">
    <h3 class="font-weight-bold mb-3"></h3>
    <strong>Dépôt A</strong>
    </h3>
    <p><strong>Type des produits :alimentaire </strong></p>
    <p><strong>Dernière modification:12/02/2019 </strong></p>
    <p><strong>Situation:50% </strong></p>
    <a href="details.html" target="_self" class="btn btn-black btn-success btn-md">vérifier</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want it to give this result: https://codepen.io/gab/pen/dJmIE

Comment: yes i know it works , it is not my code , i want to have that result on my web site, i dont know why no js or jquery code works for me , may be because I am using bootstrap Jquery cbn , i dont know why it does not work for me

Comment: It seems to work fine on the snippet as well. We can help if we cant reproduce the problem. Can you add the jquery and bootstrap cdns you are using, to the above snippet?

Comment: Are you using `document.ready` to wrap your jquery code?

Comment: @G.asma It's still unclear on what the actual problem is. Do you get a runtime error? Are things, that are supposed to happen, not happening? Are things,  that aren't supposed to happen, happening?

Comment: when i take off the bootstrap cdn and leave my js sheet it works fine , but when i add the bootstrap cdn it does not work , i cant take of the bootsrap cdn cause my web site depends on it , i just want to add other js or jquery functions to my we site , i dont know where is the problem -_-

Comment: yes i am not having the result on my web site , the edit does not happen